# Prevent my own message from being received if I report it as spam

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-messenger

I have sent a message to someone that shouldn't have got it. They haven't read it so I reported it as spam and deactivated my account. Will this definitely stop the person from seeing the message? Has anyone tried and tested this?

Answer (score 1):

After marking spam or abusive, your messages will not be readable to that person.

When you report a message as spam, that person will not be able to read your messages in his/her inbox, but what that person has sent to you will be readable for him/her in his/her inbox.

No need to deactivate your account.

Comment: Fab news! Thank you so much for letting me know. I did ask Facebook direct but they send some blanket reply that didn't actually answer me.

Comment: Do you know from past exp?

Comment: Answer is based on my experience. You also can try.